# How use nest Repeaters using a single XMLDataSource?

Tags: .net, xml, repeater, xmldatasource

I'd like to use nested repeaters that share the same XML datasource where the parent repeater passes down the datasource to the child repeater so it doesn't need to re-access the datasource for every dataitem in the parent repeater.

XPATH for Parent Repeater: "/AdpDeselection/Documents/Document[@type='A']/Funds/Fund[@cuspid='1234']"

What would I put for the DataSource attribute in the child Repeater in the code below?

I'd prefer not have to use an OnItemDataBound because I don't think it needs it but I guess I could be wrong.

```
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xdsCurrentFunds" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/CustomApps/DeselectOptions.xml" />

    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCurrentFund" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCurrentFund_ItemDataBound" DataSourceID="xdsCurrentFunds">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="CurrentFund"><%# XPath("@name")%></div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# XPath("@cuspid")%>' />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptReplacementFunds" runat="server" DataSource='WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO GET THE DATASOURCE?'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="ReplacementFund"><%# XPath("@ticker")%></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <br />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

XML Structure...

```
<Deselection>
    <Documents>
        <Document type="A">
            <Funds>
                <Fund cuspid="1234" name="CURRENT FUND NUMBER ONE">
                    <ReplacementFunds>
                        <Fund ticker="ABCD" cuspid="56785678">FUND NUMBER ONE</Fund>
                        <Fund ticker="EFGH" cuspid="23452345">FUND NUMBER TWO</Fund>
                    </ReplacementFunds>
                </Fund>
                <Fund cuspid="2345" name="CURRENT FUND NUMBER ONE">
                    <ReplacementFunds>
                        <Fund ticker="HJKL" cuspid="56785678">FUND NUMBER THREE</Fund>
                        <Fund ticker="YUIO" cuspid="23452345">FUND NUMBER FOUR</Fund>
                    </ReplacementFunds>
                </Fund>
        </Document>
    </Documents>
</Deselection>
```

Comment: You WILL need an OnItemDataBound... In the current setup... But if you use for/foreach-loops instead you don't... And that completely removes the use of repeaters... But then you need to carefully arrange the data in Lists/Arryas in the codebehind...

Comment: @sani - thanks.  However, I have seen it done this way.  I'm just not sure how they came up with what goes in the DataSource property because the example I saw didn't show the XML so I couldn't see the logic behind the ASP.NET code.

Comment: Just to make one thing clear: You will be better off with Repeaters and OnItemDataBound than rolling your own for/foreach handling. There is a performance hit with repeaters (I've been told) but unless you have a REALLY busy site Repeaters should suffice...

Comment: And for what you should put in the childs DataSource item it should be the parents datatype property that reflects the ReplacementFunds List/Array.

Comment: @sani - thanks; can you add that as an answer so that I can accept it to give you credit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found my answer after some more extensive digging.  Here's the working code:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xdsCurrentFunds" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/CustomApps/DeselectOptions.xml" />

<asp:Repeater ID="rptCurrentFund" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCurrentFund_ItemDataBound" DataSourceID="xdsCurrentFunds">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="CurrentFund"><%# XPath("@name")%></div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptReplacementFunds" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("ReplacementFunds/*") %>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="ReplacementFund"><%# XPath("@ticker")%></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <br />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This works like a charm with no OnItemDataBound code required.

[The secret sauce is the XPathSelect apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153689.aspx).

Comment: You say that no `OnItemDataBound`, but in your code there is `OnItemDataBound="rptCurrentFund_ItemDataBound"` - so which part is true?

Comment: I don't remember - could have just been commented out / empty function that was just in there when I was trying to figure it all out.